# SAGA RESAMPLING SYNTAX

Tags: error, saga, resampling, syntaxerror, cell-size

How can I solve the problem shown below:

[image: error message]

I am trying to build a plugin that allows me to resample the raster data to any desired resolution of my choice with 20 being the minimum input value, as shown below:

[image: plug-in]

Here is my code:

```
# Get layer object 
fn = 'output1' # where output1 is an output of a just created layer in an excuted action above 
# rlayer = iface.addRasterLayer(fn)
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(fn, '')
ras_out = rlayer

processing.run('saga:resampling', ras_out, True, 1, 1, [], 1, output2)
```

Comment: Please do not use ALL CAPS for question titles. "Shouting" is likely to generate downvotes.

Comment: thanks@Vince. I am looking forward to receiving any assistance with my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As the error says `processing.run()` only takes two arguments. The first should be the name of the algorithm, so you've got that part right. The second is a *dictionary* of any additional parameters. So instead of:

```
processing.run('saga:resampling', ras_out, True, 1, 1, [], 1, output2)
```

you would need something like :

```
processing.run('saga:resampling', {"PARAM_NAME" : ras_out, 
                                   "PARAM_NAME" : True, 
                                   "PARAM_NAME" : 1, 
                                   "PARAM_NAME" : 1, 
                                   "PARAM_NAME" : [], 
                                   "PARAM_NAME" : 1, 
                                   "PARAM_NAME" : output2})
```

Note that `"PARAM_NAME"` is just a place holder ... you can look up actualy parameter names with `processing.algorithmHelp('saga:resampling')`

Comment: Thank you. It helped alot.